# RTSP1.0/ 404 Stream Not Found

Tags: rtsp

I wanna get stream from camera:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Accept: application/sdpAuthorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=


RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Wed, Feb 16 2011 10:17:47 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 358


v=0
o=RTSP 1297842675200000 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.200
s=RTSP Server
t=0 0
a=range:npt=0-
a=control:*
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=framerate:20
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1;config=000001B001000001B50900000100000001200086C4004F0C14103C518F
a=control:track1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=control:track2

SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=


**RTSP/1.0 404 Stream Not Found**
CSeq: 2
Date: Wed, Feb 16 2011 10:17:48 GMT
```

If use the VLC it can work but why do i get the 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SDP *a=control:track1* and *a=control:track2*, whereas in the RTSP setup request you are using *trackID=1*. VLC is probably then doing this correctly?